# Thank you, Tim Post

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange-team, thanks, community-managers

https://twitter.com/tinkertim/status/1326989993928237057

> Tomorrow is my last day at @StackOverflow. I can't begin to say how grateful I am to everyone that made the last (almost) 8 years of my career there possible. I'll still be around as a moderator, most likely, but off to my new adventure in the K8s space after a brief rest.

Tim has been a fixture at SO as long as I've been around. Seems surreal to see him go. He's been a steady hand, especially after Shog9's departure.

May your new career help you find that new adventure you spoke of. Farewell.

Comment: SO has been working on their own post. Timing was a bit unfortunate, with a tweet going out before that post. After discussing this with a CM, we've recommended still posting that official post, closing this one as a dupe, and merging all answers to the new post. Which is what I'm doing now :) If you want to, perhaps add your own farewell from this question to the answers there too :)